# Ruby put in order columns when creating CSV document from Mongoid

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, hash, mongoid

I need to create CSV document from database. So I want to organise columns in particular order and I have template of this order and this template stored as array of headers

```
header = ["header1", "header2", "header3", "header4", "header5"]
record = [{"header4" =>"value4"}, {"header3" =>"value3"}, {"header5"=>"value5"}, {"header1"=>"value1"}, {"header2"=>"value2"}]

I need to get array like tis 
record = [{"header1" =>"value1"}, {"header2" =>"value2"}, {"header3"=>"value3"}, {"header4"=>"value4"}, {"header5"=>"value5"}]
```

but when I doing

```
csv<< mymodel.attributes.values.sort_by! { |h| header.index(h.keys[0])
```

It does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `mymodel.attributes`, you get a Hash back which maps attributes names (as strings) to their values. If your attribute names are `header1` through `header5` then `mymodel.attributes` will be something like this:

```
{
  'header1' => 'value1',
  'header2' => 'value2',
  'header3' => 'value3',
  'header4' => 'value4',
  'header5' => 'value5'
}
```

Of course, the order depends on how things come out of MongoDB. The easiest way to extract a bunch of values from a Hash in a specified order is to use [`values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
mymodel.attributes.values_at(*header)
```